# И смех(,) и грех

Tags: пунктуация

Вроде, не было такого вопроса (по крайней мере, я не нашел). Нужна ли запятая в обороте "и смех(,) и грех"? Вроде бы это устойчивый оборот, но, с другой стороны, тут перечисление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На этот счет у Розенталя есть четкое правило: "Запятая не ставится внутри цельных выражений, образованных двумя словами с противоположным значением, соединенными повторяющимися союзами И,НИ, например: и смех и горе, и стар и млад, и так и этак, и холод и голод, ни рыба ни мясо, ни стать ни сесть, ни себе ни людям...